# Extract SST values from netcdf with R

Tags: r

I want to extract  SST values from Netcdf file with R software. I downloaded temperature data from "https://podaac.jpl.nasa.gov/dataset/OISST_HR_NRT-GOS-L4-MED-v2.0". I need to extract temperature value in specific area ( longitude between -2 and 10; latitude between 35 to 40) and  organize them by year and then calculate the average per month.

I don't know how to do this because I don't know how to read the Gregorian calendar.

I tried to apply scripts but:

```
> library(ncdf4)
> rm(list=ls())
> fn <- "D:/logiciel/KHAMES/OISST_HR_NRT-GOS-L4-MED-v2.0.nc"
> cdf<- nc_open(fn)
> nc
lat <- ncdf4::ncvar_get(cdf, varid="lat")
lon <- ncdf4::ncvar_get(cdf, varid="lon")
time <- ncdf4::ncvar_get(cdf, varid="time")
sst <- ncdf4::ncvar_get(cdf, varid="analysed_sst")
time_d <- as.Date(time, format="%j", origin=as.Date("1981-01-01"))
time_years <- format(time_d, "%Y")
time_months <- format(time_d, "%m")
time_year_months <- format(time_d, "%Y-%
```

Comment: what is `sst`? Is it the temperature?

Answer (score 1):

I'll assume that you have correctly extracted the data from the netcdf file, and that you're struggling with the calculation of mean sst for every month.

Here is what worked for me, and it might be what you seek:

```
lon <- sample(1:5, size = 200, replace = TRUE)
lat <- sample(35:40, size = 200, replace = TRUE)
sst <- 1:200
time_years <- rep(rep(1:10, each = 10), 2)
time_months <- rep(rep(1:10, times = 10), 2)
time_year_months <- paste(time_years, time_months, sep = "-")
library(dplyr)
tibble(lat = as.numeric(lat), lon = as.numeric(lon), sst = as.numeric(sst), time_years, time_months, time_year_months) %>%
  filter(lon > -2, lon < 10, lat > 35, lat < 40) %>%
  group_by(time_year_months) %>%
  summarise(mean_sst = mean(sst))
```