# Crop netcdf files in R

Tags: r, ncdf4, r-stars

I'm trying to crop a netcdf file with a polygon with `stars` package from daily netcdf data. I think I have managed to do it and could get this plot

[image]

with this script

```
library(tidyverse)
library(sf)
library(stars)

# Input nc file
nc.file <- "20220301120000-NCEI-L4_GHRSST-SSTblend-AVHRR_OI-GLOB-v02.0-fv02.1.nc"
# read nc data
nc.data <- read_ncdf(nc.file, var="analysed_sst")

# Read mask coordinates
coordenades.poligon <- read_csv("coordenades_poligon.csv")
colnames(coordenades.poligon) <- c("lon","lat")

# Build sf polygon to crop data
polygon <- coordenades.poligon %>%
  st_as_sf(coords = c("lon", "lat"), crs = 4326) %>%
  summarise(geometry = st_combine(geometry)) %>%
  st_cast("POLYGON")

# Crop data
nc.stars.crop <- st_crop(nc.data,polygon)

# plot
ggplot() + geom_stars(data=nc.stars.crop) +
  coord_equal() + theme_void() +
  scale_x_discrete(expand=c(0,0))+
  scale_y_discrete(expand=c(0,0))
```

Now I would like to combine lon, lat and analysed_sst in a data frame. I managed to extract coordinates with

```
nc.stars.coords <- as.data.frame(st_coordinates(nc.stars.crop))
```

But can't find how to get the corresponding sst values to cbind with longitude and latitude. Maybe there are other solutions with `ncdf4` package.

Thank you very much for your help

**EDIT 1**

Link to SST original data (nc file): [SST data](https://www.dropbox.com/s/9ed909yb7byaasx/20220301120000-NCEI-L4_GHRSST-SSTblend-AVHRR_OI-GLOB-v02.0-fv02.1.nc?dl=0)

**EDIT 2**
Added head of coordenades_poligons.csv. First columns are longitude and latitude points, third column is the area ID and fourth one denotes the season. These are just the coordinates of a single area filtered by ID and season.

```
12.5,44.5,Z1,S
2,44.5,Z1,S
0,41.5,Z1,S
4,40,Z1,S
9,40,Z1,S
9,42,Z1,S
0,41.5,Z2,S
```

Comment: Hi. Is the original data somewhere, so I can replicate it? Also, did you see this post by any chance? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49928812/extract-sst-values-from-netcdf-with-r?rq=1

Comment: hI @Datapumpernickel, link added. Will check the post, thanks

Comment: please put some example data for coordenades.poligon in the question.  read.csv is unusable for anyone else who does not have the file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am making assumptions here, because this is not my area of expertise, but you are able to simply transform this into a dataset using the `raster`-package. This seems to be the way to go, also according to [this](https://semba-blog.netlify.app/11/03/2018/converting-netcdf-files-into-data-frame/) author.

```
raster::as.data.frame(nc.stars.crop, xy = TRUE)
```

At least for me this worked. And then you could transform it back into a simple features object, if you are so inclined with

```
raster::as.data.frame(nc.stars.crop, xy = TRUE) %>% 
sf::st_as_sf(coords = c('lon','lat'))
```

However, the transformation to lon/lat is not really exact, because it produces point data, whereas the original information is raster data. So there is clearly information that gets lost.

`sf::st_as_sf()` seems to work out of the box for this, but I am not sure, because I have no way to validate the transformation of the original data. For me the following worked:

```r
read_ncdf('20220301120000-NCEI-L4_GHRSST-SSTblend-AVHRR_OI-GLOB-v02.0-fv02.1.nc', var="analysed_sst") %>%
  sf::st_as_sf()
```

This creates polygons, the size of your initial raster tiles and seems to conserve all necessary information.

Finally, here is a work-around to extracting exactly the data you were plotting. You can access the data that ggplot used, by assigning the ggplot to a variable and then accessing the data layer.

```
p <- ggplot() + geom_stars(data=nc.stars.crop) +
coord_equal() + theme_void() +
scale_x_discrete(expand=c(0,0))+
scale_y_discrete(expand=c(0,0))

p$layers[[1]]$data
```

Comment: As you say it is may be not the better canonical answer but it seems to work. I found another workaround with the "old" `reshape2` package. Gonna check both methods. Thanks for the effort.

Comment: I have edited the answer to include a link, citing the `raster` package. I think at least I cant do more canonical. But lets see if somebody else contributes something better!